# Two similar meshes and points between them

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have 2 meshes which are of the same object in different poses. I'd like to get meshes which are midway between these, as if they are being transformed into each other. They aren't rigged with armatures.

Can Blender do this, if so how and what is the result like?

Seems relatively straightforward in 2D but I imagine harder on 3D.

Thanks in advance.
K

Comment: Are you interested in a solution with *Geometry Nodes*? ...that would possibly work (depending on your mesh).

Answer (score 2):

The meshes need to have the exact same topology or this wont work.

Here I have two object with the same topology but with different shapes:
[image]

Now select first the object with the shape to be transferred, and last the object you want to transfer the shape to:
[image]

Then in the shape key pannel, click the arrow and select join as shape:
[image]

Now you can play with the shape key value to get your model to be transformed:
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGSZS.jpg